# MySQL query displaying more data than expected

Tags: mysql, join

I have MySql database connected to my Java app. My users can choose meals, category of meals, quantity, write note and order that meals. I store that orders in table `usluga_hrana`. At the moment I am working only with meals service but I have other services too, like drink service, wake up service and others. Thats why I need one more table for all orders from different services and its called `narudzba`. Now I need to display values of all these atributes in one query: `broj_sobe` (room number, table narudzba), `id_narudzba` (id order, table narudzba), `naziv_kategorija` (category name, table kategorija_jela), `naziv_hrane` (name of meal, table naziv_jela), `kolicina` (quantity, table usluga_hrana), `napomena` (note, table usluga_hrana), `datum_vrijeme` (date and time, table usluga_hrana) and `izvrseno` (done, table narudzba). Problem is that all these atributes are in different tables and when I execute my query, it displays me multiple values of orders, meals etc.

My tables are connected this way:
PK `id_usluga` (table `usluga`) is FK `id_usluga` in table narudzba
PK `id_usluga` (table `usluga`) is FK `id_usluga` in table usluga_hrana
PK `id_kategorija` (table `kategorija_jela`) is FK `id_kategorija` in table usluga_hrana
PK `id_hrana` (table `naziv_jela`) is FK `id_hrana` in table usluga_hrana
PK `id_kategorija` (table `kategorija_jela`) is FK `id_kategorija` in table naziv_jela

Here is album of my tables and result of my query with multiple values: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJSnM.jpg
Here is album with rest of my tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2N7n.jpg

Here is my query:

```
SELECT n.broj_soba, n.id_narudzba, kj.naziv_kategorija, nj.naziv_hrane, us.kolicina,   
us.napomena, us.datum_vrijeme, n.izvrseno
FROM narudzba n
JOIN usluga u ON n.id_usluga = u.id_usluga
JOIN usluga_hrana us ON u.id_usluga = us.id_usluga
JOIN naziv_jela nj ON us.id_jela = nj.id_jela
JOIN kategorija_jela kj ON nj.id_kategorija = kj.id_kategorija
GROUP BY n.id_narudzba, us.id_usluga_hrana
```

I think my query is not good...

Answer (score 0):

you name your table in not-English make us very hard to read/understand/think even though you already translate it to English :)

Your duplicate data can come from your query or your data table

I can see in your `usluga_hrana` table you have to records of **Tomato soup** (id=10) with **different quantity** (4 and 7). That make your query result **2 line of Tomato soup**. Another example, You have 4 records of Greek Salad also but because 3 of them get the same quantity=1 so when query run, it return 2 row (quantity 1 and 2)

Not sure what you want, but if you do not want query result duplicate, you should **not** `SELECT` the quantity column and do `DISTINCT` the result if needed